# Tenant's permitted use of rented parking space

Tags: germany, rental-property

I rent an apartment in a block of flats. Tenants are given an assigned car parking space in a basement-level parking lot, for which they also pay a monthly rent.

The landlord has written to us stating that the car parking space is **permitted only for parking one’s private car**. They went on to state that a set of spare tyres or a bicycle and/or bicycle trailer are "tolerated". Claiming fire and safety regulations, no other personal items may be stored.

As my cellar is full, I have placed some bulkier items i.e. an old pram and buggy in my otherwise redundant car parking space.

- The items are folded together and placed against the back wall
- 90% of the parking space area is still free.
- My items do not obstruct any access or fire escape route.

My understanding of the notice is that I am not permitted to do this. Why?

What is the reason for such a regulation? Obviously they wouldn't want tenants dumping a huge mountain of junk in their parking areas, but what risk does a pram constitute?

Can the landlord force me to remove my stuff from my own rented parking space?

Thanks for any insights into this situation.

Comment: I suspect the answer will depend on the details of the contract.

Comment: Fire load is a serious concern in garages.

Comment: _"Obviously they wouldn't want tenants dumping a huge mountain of junk in their parking areas, but what risk does a pram constitute?"_ Try coming up with a rule that you think allows the sensible and disallows the insensible. Now, how sure are you that you have not left **any** gap for insensible things to happen, or sensible things to be unnecessarily prohibited? Additionally, how much time is this taking you and what do you really personally stand to gain? As much as I dislike them in general, near-to-zero tolerance rules are almost always created by absence of a more sensible boundary.

Comment: You mention you "also pay a monthly rent" for the parking space. That wording implies that this is a different rent from the apartment one. Is that correct? In other words, do they come as an inevitable package deal or not?

Comment: Can you buy a cheap junk vehicle, put it in the space, and then put your stuff in the vehicle?

Comment: anecdotally I can tell about that situation that we regularily have the case that when a fire inspection takes place, they tell us to make sure that our tenants remove everything combustible, be it too much tires or cardboard boxes or anything, because they contribute to the fire load

Comment: @user4574 or even put the stuff in a bicycle trailer or roof box. A clause about only taxed/insured/roadworthy vehicles would be unsurprising and make for an expensive storage box on wheels.

Comment: You're lucky that bicycles are tolerated.  [People have gone to court and lost](https://www.haufe.de/immobilien/verwaltung/stellplatz-in-der-tiefgarage-ist-nicht-fuer-fahrrad-da_258_337110.html) for wanting to park their bicycles in their assigned parking space.

Comment: German (and not only German) law privileges cars (perhaps due to its powerful car lobby). Not only do cars get privileged access to parking garages; even more extremely so, in many places you can simply leave your car on **public** property, such as on the street. You might not even have to pay for it! Try to put a sofa or any other personal property in a public parking place and see how long it takes until you're told you can't do that...

Comment: [Wouldn't a buggy count as a vehicle](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=buggy&t=ffab&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images)? I don't understand how it can be folded. Maybe the "pram"/baby-carriage can be somehow mounted on the top or back of the buggy, or at least maybe be fit in the passenger and/or driver's seat of the buggy?

Comment: @JoL Presumably they mean the British version of a "buggy," like a stroller.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> My understanding of the notice is that I am not permitted to do this. Why?

Because the "Garagenverordnung" ([Link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garagenverordnung)) of most federal states and other regulations say so. Your landlord is probably the owner of the building, so it is on them to make sure it is followed. They do this by telling their tennants to follow the regulations.

The [ADAC](https://www.adac.de/rund-ums-haus/wohnen/recht/garagen-nutzung/) summarizes this as follows:

> **What is allowed to be stored in the garage?**
>
> In addition to the number of vehicles in relation to the number of parking spaces in a garage (single garage one, double garage two, etc.), items belonging to the car may be stored. This includes, for example
>
> - tires
> - Roof racks and roof boxes
> - jacks
> - Operating materials such as antifreeze, oil, windshield cleaner - at least in insignificant quantities
> - Some fuel in limited quantities (the garage regulations of the respective federal state may contain information on this)

Being the biggest German automobile club, I think they know what they are talking about, even without quoting the exact line of the regulation.

> What is the reason for such a regulation? Obviously they wouldn't want tenants dumping a huge mountain of junk in their parking areas, but what risk does a pram constitute?

Well, they have to draw a line somewhere. I'm not sure when "a mountain" of something starts legally. Or at which point enough stuff becomes a fire hazard. The easiest way is to just say "in a place designated as garage, a car and things to operate a car are legal to store, other things are not. So for example I'm pretty sure a child car seat would be fine, a stroller is not. Is one more of a hazard than the other? No. But that is not the point. There has to be a line somewhere and this is where the legislative drew it.

> Can the landlord force me to remove my stuff from my own rented parking space?

Depends on your definition of "force", but they can have it removed if you don't do it, since it is against building regulations and a safety/fire hazard and they can terminate your lease for cause (and evict you, if you don't move out on your own) if you don't comply. So yes... they can do that.

Comment: American here: what is the applicability of these regulations? Is it illegal to use a privately owned garage for storage in Germany?? Or is this for commercial/shared garages only? In America, a lot of garages get used to store pretty much anything except cars, so this notion is a little wild to me.

Comment: @GlennWillen In your privately owned garage, where a fire would not impact any neighbors, nobody cares (but you can't convert them into an apartment because insulation, sanitation and similar requirements, and if a garage fire causes your house to burn down you'll have an interesting conversation with your insurance). However, if a garage is shared, and stuff that happens inside the garage could affect somebody else, there's a lot more regulation designed to prevent the spread of fire, spill of hazardous liquids, and many things more.

Comment: @GlennWillen my reading (I'm not German), the overall regulations apply to all garages, but many subsections distinguish between "small", "medium", and "large" garages, with ones under 100m^2 being "small". For instance the Rhineland-Palatinate GarStellVO says "In Mittel- und Großgaragen ist die Aufbewahrung von brennbaren Stoffen außerhalb von Kraftfahrzeugen nicht zulässig" ("The storage of combustible materials outside of motor vehicles is not permitted in medium-sized and large garages").

Comment: @GlennWillen It is often illegal to use your private garage for storage (but in 99% of the cases, nobody cares). The reason: Garages are allowed to build at places where you would not be allowed to build a shed, garden house etc. The idea was to reduce the number of cars parking on the street. They did not want people just build garages for storage and then park their car on the street.

Comment: @GlennWillen While private garages are certainly "small" and don't have to have all the fancy extras big public garages need, I have not found any excemption for them. As you  often don't need a permit to build them, that makes sense, since building a "garage" without a permit and then using it as something that would have needed (and maybe not even gotten) a permit would be an obvious loophole. That said, once you close the door, who could say what you do in your private garage?

Comment: @GlennWillen Germany has more people renting than owning their places, so there's more pressure for the country to have rules in place.  It's probably also fair to say that Germany is a bit more rules-centred than other places!

Comment: @nvoigt I guess this is one of the things you need evil neighbours for.

Answer (score 29):

### What does your contract say?

If it identifies the space as a parking space, then it is not a storeroom, and the landlord would be within their rights not to allow you to treat it as one, irrespective of whether there are regulations preventing it or not.

### What do the building rules say?

Notwithstanding the lease, if the building has rules not allowing storage in car spaces, those would be enforcable on the tenant. Such rules might be in place for any reason, including that storing stuff in car spaces just looks messy.

### What do the regulations say?

Notwithstanding either of the above, if it's illegal to store stuff in parking spaces, it's illegal. Why it's illegal is off-topic for this site but it's likely to be more about increasing the potential fuel load in a fire than blocking escape paths - car spaces full of cars burn differently to car spaces full of paper, timber and flammable liquids.

Comment: QA asked what are the rules. They did not ask for a recommendation to follow the rules. I guess they already know it by themselves.